# PayPal Integration Methods / Simple Solution with safe Return-URL

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, returnurl

I do need to integrate PayPal on a website with a single click, always the same price and no shopping cart (A Pay Now/Donate Button I guess would ok!). However: I need to have the ability of a custom return URL and need to have a safe Return-URL (including GET Parameters, Token, Checksum or whatsoever). Also IPN should work.

Now: I am so lost. What type of integration can I possibly choose? There's PayPal Express, PayPal Basic, a single HTML Form Button, PayPal Starter, API solutions and SDK's. Between tons of Documents I just don't know which solution I can take.

Please, somebody any suggestions?

Many many Thanks!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for simple, a single button is probably what you're looking for. Check the documentation and see if it provides the functionality you need. If I remember correctly, this option does, but haven't implemented PayPal for quite a while now, so I might be wrong.

Either way, go for the options with the most basic set of features, and work your way up until you find the solution that does provide all your required features.

Signing up on PayPal's x.com developer network will definitely help a lot too, as you can test all the features in a sandbox environment.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your message!
Yes I guess I do have to go the way up, starting with a simple button and go from there. I've already made some headway.
Signing up on x.com is certainly a good idea, thanks!!
Maybe this might be useful for somebody sometime (just found it):
https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide/buynow_buttons.html#1070412

Many thanks again!

Mike